# Why python3 can't find already installed module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip

I have 2.7 and 3.7 version of Python on my MAC. I'm using Visual Studio Code as an IDE and I want to reference [Yahoo Earnings module](https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-earnings-calendar/) as part of my script. If I use 2.7 python version, I can build and run the script. But if I use 3.7 version of Python, I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
  No module named 'yahoo_earnings_calendar'
```

Here's the output `pip3 list` command showing that I have yahoo-earnings-calendar 0.6.0 module installed

`

```
bash-3.2$ pip3 listPackage                 Version
----------------------- ---------
arrow                   0.14.7
certifi                 2020.6.20
chardet                 3.0.4
ics                     0.7
idna                    2.10
pip                     20.1.1
python-dateutil         2.8.1
requests                2.24.0
setuptools              47.1.0
six                     1.15.0
TatSu                   5.5.0
urllib3                 1.25.10
**yahoo-earnings-calendar 0.6.0**
```

I'll be happy if someone can assist me to find out what may cause this issue.

Comment: looks like you have a third python installation you are not aware of

Comment: What does `<your_python_interpreter> -m pip list` say?

Comment: Also you can set the python interpreter used by VSCode, make sure it's the same one. Also pip installs can be user-dependent as well.

Comment: @KlausD. I've just saw I have 3 versions of 3.x Python - 3.73, 3.8.1 and 3.8.5. If I choose the latest 3.8,5 as an interpreter and run `python3 -m pip list` I can see I have my desired module installed and I can run the script without errors. Thank you so much.

Comment: Some reference on the topic: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score -1):

You might have multiple versions of python3 on your system. I for instance have both python 3.7 and 3.6 on my system. if i use pip3 it installs the packages in my version 3.6 install.

by running

```
pip3 --version
```

you can see which version of python pip3 is comming from in my case: 3.6

```
pip 19.3.1 from /home/andreas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

make sure to use the right version of python when using the module

in my case if i want to use pip3 modules i need to write

```
python3.6 someprogram.py
```

when running a program

because if i just write

```
python someprogram.py
```

it uses python 3.7 and the module will therfore not be available